# unique elements in two lists

Tags: python

I was thinking if it's possible to create a list of unique elements from two lists shorter but without using `set`?

```
l1 = [1,1,2,2,3]
l2 = [2,1,3,3,4]
unique = []
for elem in l1+l2:
    if elem not in unique:
        unique.append(elem)
print unique

[1,2,3,4]
```

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Uhhh just use a `set`. I guess `dict.fromkeys(l1+l2).keys()`, but that's pretty much cheating.

Comment: @AdamSmith it's very interesting solution

Comment: @pianista: Didn't downvote, but I think the reason is: *Why don't use `set`? That's why Python has `set`, that's what does it do.*

Comment: I specifically asked if it's possible without set @KevinGuan

Comment: @pianista: Yes I know, but use `set` to do this is the best way...

Comment: This is a valid question.  Downvoters don't know computer science

Comment: This is a silly question if OP doesn't explain why he doesn't want to use `set`. Yes, it's obviously possible; no, I'm not going to spend time writing an answer without some sort of use case for it. As is, this takes up space on the front page that would be better used by actually useful and/or interesting questions, and so I downvoted.

Comment: But you have time to post such argument *smh*

Comment: Python `set` actually uses dict like object internally with dummy value.  So I'd suggest to implement using dict.  http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup

Comment: @OP Why not `set`? `set` is implemented using hash table, so even if you use any data structure that will not efficient.

Comment: @python because i know how to solve the problem but i'm interested in different solutions if they exist

Comment: thanks for the info @KenjiNoguchi

Comment: I'm a DV'er and a close vote. It's a bad question because there's no rationale for not using set. The answer to "How do you do this" is "Use a set." The answer to "How do you do this without a set" is "Don't use Python."

Comment: question was "Is it possible?".I see this place became not it was intended to be.

Comment: Check my answer and benchmark result. Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should be using `set` in Python to find unique values because it efficiently gives you the unique elements.

If you want to use `list` then the code you have provided is right! If you are using `numpy` in your code (which might be a good choice for larger amounts of data), check out `numpy.unique`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> wordsList = [u'nowplaying', u'PBS', u'PBS', u'nowplaying', u'job', u'debate', u'thenandnow']
>>> np.unique(wordsList)
array([u'PBS', u'debate', u'job', u'nowplaying', u'thenandnow'], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

Also look into this benchmark results for finding `unique values` [Link](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark)

Code is provided on the link, but adding here for your reference:

```
def f1(seq):
   # not order preserving
   set = {}
   map(set.__setitem__, seq, [])
   return set.keys()

def f2(seq): 
   # order preserving
   checked = []
   for e in seq:
       if e not in checked:
           checked.append(e)
   return checked

def f3(seq):
   # Not order preserving
   keys = {}
   for e in seq:
       keys[e] = 1
   return keys.keys()

def f4(seq): 
   # order preserving
   noDupes = []
   [noDupes.append(i) for i in seq if not noDupes.count(i)]
   return noDupes

def f5(seq, idfun=None): 
   # order preserving
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       # in old Python versions:
       # if seen.has_key(marker)
       # but in new ones:
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result

def f6(seq):
   # Not order preserving    
   set = Set(seq)
   return list(set)
```

**Benchmark Results**

```
* f2 13.24
* f4 11.73
* f5 0.37
f1 0.18
f3 0.17
f6 0.19
```

Comment: f2, essentially same as op's solution, is O(n^2) in terms of time complexity.  As the result shows it's one of the slowest algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

Specifically using your code

```
 l1 = [1,1,2,2,3]
 l2 = [2,1,3,3,4]
 unique=set(l1+l2)
```

If you wanted it as a list not as a set

```
unique=list(set(l1+l2))
```

Comment: it's not an answer since i specifically asked not to use set